# Nagios check_http gives 'HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable' for HAProxy'd site

Tags: ssl, http, nagios, haproxy

I asked this on stackoverflow, but I think it's better suited for here.

Can't figure this one out!

OS: CentOS 6.6 (Up-To-Date)

I get the following 503 error when using my nagios `check_http` check (or curl) to query an SSL site served via HAProxy 1.5.

```
[root@nagios ~]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -v -H example.com -S1
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: check_http/v2.0 (nagios-plugins 2.0)
Connection: close
Host: example.com


https://example.com:443/ is 212 characters
STATUS: HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
**** HEADER ****
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
**** CONTENT ****
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>

HTTP CRITICAL: HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable - 212 bytes in 1.076 second response time |time=1.075766s;;;0.000000 size=212B;;;0
[root@nagios ~]# curl -I https://example.com
HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

However. I can access the site fine via any browser; (200 OK), and also `curl -I https://example.com` from another server:

```
root@localhost:~# curl -I https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 18 Feb 2015 14:36:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Feb 2015 14:36:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
```

The HAProxy server is runnning on pfSense 2.2.

I see that HAProxy returns an HTTP/1.0 for nagios and HTTP/1.1 from elsewhere. So is it my `check_http` plugin causing this or is it `curl`?

Is my server just not sending the HOST header? If so, how can I resolve this?

Comment: It could be the host header, but it depends on your haproxy config. Can you provide the config?

Comment: Stupid question: the monitored website (example.com) resolves to the same ip on both machines?

Comment: @TimStoop Will pull the HAProxy config from pfSense in a short while.

Comment: @Dan Yep. Resolves to the same IP on both machines. HAProxy is actually SSL proxying for another site on the same backend but that site doesn't get any 503 errors!

Comment: Why are you using -S1? Just use -S or --ssl, and show us the output.

Comment: Maybe the site reacts differently because of Nagios' uncommon User Agent string.

Answer (score 1):

check_http has an option called `--sni`

You need to use that option

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to put the "-u" option for the url?
I also used the IP adress and hostname. I also have a HAProxy, and the same message as you at the begining.

I used the command:

```
./check_http -H example.com -I 8.8.8.8 -p 80 -u http://example.com/
```

And now it's work!

Answer (score 0):

### Heres how to fix this!

You have to edit the /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg and change the https arument **"-I" to "-H"**

This will tell it to lookup hostname instead of an dip-address specified in your http_check block in server config:
/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/yourserver.cfg

**from:**

```
    # 'check_http' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
        }
```

**To:**

```
    # 'check_http' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
        }
```